# Is all evil an invention of angels?

Tags: malach-angel

In the book of Enoch it says that the fallen angels "Watchers" came to earth and taught humans evil, astrology, how to fight, cosmetics, drink blood and so on.

Comment: I can't vote to Migrate to another site. I think it should be on another site, but the only site I'm able to recommend is Meta MY, which is also not correct. It could go to another biblical site or a Christian site, maybe.

Comment: what is enoch? Everything is created by Hashem. Anything created by a creation is not an actual creation but a reforming of a creation. For example if I make a table I didn't create the table but I used a material Hashem created to form the table. Not sure how evil would fit that description. Also in your question you seem to be claiming that whatever a "fallen angel" is learned evil from people.

Comment: @Dude "whatever a "fallen angel" is learned evil from people"Not  at all,they did learn us evil,there is no claim.

Comment: @Eagel here is a direct quote from your question, "came to earth and learned humans evil". If this isn't your intention than you need to reword your question. Also define what you are talking about specifically. What is Enoch and what are "fallen angels"?

Comment: @Dude based on the comment, Eagel seems to be using "learned" instead of "taught" Seems like an English usage problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Judaism. Also, unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @msh210 There are many jews that agree that angels came to earth,and taught humans evil,how can then one claim that this is not judaisme?

Comment: Re your comment "@msh210 There are many jews that agree that angels came to earth,and taught humans evil,how can then one claim that this is not judaisme?": Please see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: this site is about Judaism, not Jews. And I see nothing about Judaism (or Jews, incidentally) in this question post.

Comment: The book of Enoch is not accepted as cannonical by Jews.  The Book doesn't exist in Hebrew, and only is found in Greek and Coptic translations.  As such, the contents cannot be verified as being authentically Jewish.  That being said, the very concept that evil is a by-product of fallen-angels is built around Christian ideas based on "Paradise Lost" by Milton.  Just because 'Jews' say things doesn't mean this is reflective of normative Judaism.  As an example Karl Marx was Jewish and an atheist - his views of religion are at complete odds with Judaism and, I might add, Christianity.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/130262/7303

Answer (score 4):

The Book of Enoch is [not](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67984/1362) one which is considered part of the biblical canon for Jews.

No -- evil is a part of the overall creation of the world as executed by God.

Check out Isaiah 45:7

> Who forms light and creates darkness, Who makes peace and creates evil; I am the Lord, Who makes all these.       זיוֹצֵר אוֹר וּבוֹרֵא חֹשֶׁךְ עֹשֶׂה שָׁלוֹם וּבוֹרֵא רָע אֲנִי יְהֹוָה עֹשֶׂה כָל אֵלֶּה: