# Are there any non-inspired writings before Philo's time?

Tags: history, jewish-books, oral-torah

I came across some writings of [Philo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philo), which I found very interesting, and wondered if there are any Jewish writings either around his time (circa 20 BCE to circa 50 CE) or before. I looked around and all I found were writings after Philo's time. My question is this: Are there any writings in Judaism say after Moses to the time of Philo? For those of you familiar with Christianity, it would be analogous of asking about the writings of the Church Fathers.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Hebrew_writings

Comment: Is the whole Old Testament part of Moses?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Tomas. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @AlBerko I saw that before asking the question and didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Have you looked at the Apocrypha?

Comment: @TomasPalamas Yes, tons. All the writings (ketuvim) and the Prophets (navi'im) -- in short, the rest of the Old Testament -- were written before Philo. From around the same time as Philo there are Josephus and Rashbi, and, like, Maccabees

Comment: @TomasPalamas Most of these, though, are considered "inspired"

Comment: See [Old Testament pseudepigrapha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Old_Testament_pseudepigrapha), [deuterocanonical books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterocanonical_books), [Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint), and [Dead Sea scrolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Sea_Scrolls).

Comment: See also [early Jewish writings](http://www.earlyjewishwritings.com), [Josephus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus), [Samaritan Pentateuch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_Pentateuch), and [Ethiopian bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_Tewahedo_biblical_canon).

Answer (score 3):

How about [Ben Sira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirach)?   It was composed around ~200 BCE, and is not considered part of the Jewish Bible.

Comment: Well as a Catholic, we accept that as canon. Do you know of any other writings around that time?

Comment: hmm... pretty much any widely known work from that time was canonized by *someone*  (e.g. Enoch, Macabees, Tobit).   What about some of the relatively  recently uncovered Dead Sea scrolls (e.g. the "War Scroll" or "Community Rule")?

Answer (score 2):

Depending how far back you want to go, all of the Jewish Bible (*Tanakh*, incl the [Prophets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevi%27im) and [Writings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketuvim)) takes place from Moses's death until 500 BCE.

Closer to Philo's time, the [Mishna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah), compiled by [R Yehuda HaNasi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ha-Nasi#Compiler_of_the_Mishnah), is a collection of halakhic principles and sayings quoting Sages, including some living in the first two centuries CE, e.g., for the period which interests you

- [Hillel the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_the_Elder), lived 110 BCE to 10 CE
- [Shammai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shammai), lived 50 BCE to 30 CE

If you want to read a part of the Mishna more easily understandable without background, the Mishna tractate [Ethics of the Fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirkei_Avot) would be a very good place to start, (e.g., [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682498/jewish/English-Text.htm) or [there](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1?lang=bi)). Its beginning actually lists the order of transmission of the Torah from Moses to later Sages, starting with Moshe, Joshua, the Elders, the Prophets, the Men of the Great Assembly and [Shimon HaTzadik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_the_Just) (ca. 300 BCE)

Comment: I don't see how the _Mishnah_ (which was published around 200 CE) is a "_Jewish writing either_ [from] _around_ [Philo's] _time (circa 20 BCE to circa 50 CE) or before_" (paraphrasing from the question), not in the sense that Philo's writings are.

Comment: Because it is a compilation of sayings from people from these ages, passed from teacher to student, and compiled in writing later

Comment: I've never heard about the Ethics, thanks. However, Tamir Evan is correct. I want writings from the time period I specified. Also, I mentioned non-inspired, which means outside the Jewish Bible.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [Book of Enoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch), composed between 300 BCE to 100 BCE, which is (as well as Ben Sira) [not](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67978/is-the-book-of-enoch-part-of-judaism/67984#67984) considered part of the biblical canon for Jews.